# Knockout dynamic css not working?

Tags: knockout.js

Trying something pretty simple here:

```
 <div class="posted-by-area" data-bind="css: getCss">
```

In my vm:

```
self.getCss = function(data) {
    return 'trustedUserGold';
};
```

But the rendered class is the function text, so I see `class="function(){ etc.."`.

How can I use a function as opposed to an observable here?  This is being used in a loop and I'd like to pass the $data into the function to determine class based on its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the function.

```
<div data-bind="css: getCss()" ></div>
```